# Create an alias to a function with a parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

The `pprint` function includes a parameter `sort_dicts=True` which doesn’t suit me.

I know that something like:

```py
from pprint import pprint
thing = pprint
```

will effectively create an alias to the `pprint` function.

How do I define a function which acts as an alias to the `pprint` function with `sort_dicts=False` ? Something like this:

```
#   I know this is wrong
newpp = pprint(…, sort_dicts=False)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for *partial application* of a function. In Python, there is a standard library function called [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) that will do it for you.

```
from functools import partial

newpp = partial(pprint, sort_dicts=False)
```

You can do this by hand in Python, too. If you're interested in seeing the mechanism behind it, you can check out the link above, which has an example implementation.

Note that, with `partial`, somebody can still explicitly override your keyword arguments. If I call `newpp(x, sort_dicts=True)`, then my `sort_dicts` wins over yours. But if the caller is cooperative and doesn't supply the keyword argument, then yours gets taken.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the reference. I have posted a simplified manual version as it applies to my particular application.

Answer (score 1):

I have accept Silvio’s answer, which refers to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial. In turn, that reference includes a manual way of doing this, though it’s a way of emulating the `partial()` function more generally.

In answer to my original question, I have ended up with the following:

```py
import pprint
def pq(*fargs, **fkeywords):
    keywords = { 'sort_dicts': False }
    newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
    return pprint.pprint(*fargs, **newkeywords)

elements = {
    'H': 'Hydrogen', 'He': 'Helium', 'Li': 'Lithium',
    'Be': 'Beryllium', 'B': 'Boron', 'C': 'Carbon',
    'N': 'Nitrogen', 'O': 'Oxygen', 'F': 'Flourine', 'Ne': 'Neon'
}

pprint.pprint(elements) #   sorted
pq(elements)            #   unsorted
```

Of course the question was how to do this in generally, but it’s even simpler once you get your head around the arguments.